# How to get class_to_idx map for Custom Dataset in Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch

I am attempting transfer learning with a CNN (vgg19) on the Oxford102 category dataset consisting of 8189 samples of flowers labeled from 1 through 102. Instead of loading the data with ImageFolder, which requires a tedious process of  structuring my data into train, valid and test folders with each class being a sub-folder holding my images, I decided to load it in using the Custom Dataset class following

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html

A subset of the code I wrote up for my project

```
    data_dir_path = 'data/images/'
    labels_path = 'data/imagelabels.mat'
    class_label_path = 'data/class_label_map'

    # standard normalization for Imagenet models mean: [0.485, 0.456,0.406],
    # std :[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

    data_transforms = {
'train': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomRotation(45),
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
]),
'valid': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
]),
'test': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
]),
   }


    class MyDataset(Dataset):

        def __init__(self, image_labels, data_dir, transform=None):

    """

    :param image_labels_path: path to our labels
    :param root_dir: the directory which houses our images
    :param transform: apply any transform on our sample
    """

    self.image_labels = image_labels
    self.root_dir = data_dir
    self.transform = transform

        def __len__(self):
    label_dict = scipy.io.loadmat(self.image_labels)
    return len(label_dict['labels'][0])

        def __getitem__(self, idx):

    image_path_list = [os.path.join(self.root_dir, filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.root_dir)]

    image = Image.open(image_path_list[idx])

    label_dict = scipy.io.loadmat(self.image_labels)
    label_list = label_dict['labels'][0]

    # label index for pytorch should start form zero
    # so subtract -1 from each class
    label_list[:] = [i - 1 for i in label_list]
    label = label_list[idx]  

    if self.transform:
        image = self.transform(image)

    return image, label

    image_datasets = {x: MyDataset(image_labels=labels_path, data_dir=data_dir_path, transform=data_transforms[x]) for x in
              ['train', 'valid', 'test']}
```

my model class instance inherited from nn.Module is

```
    classifier = Neural(25088, [4096], 102)
```

I have subtracted -1 from my label list since Pytorch expects labels to start from 0. Thus 0 through 101 for 102 labels. Correct me if I am wrong cause I get a "current target >=0 and current target <= n_classes failed" error if I don't subtract one.

class_label_map is a dict which maps class labels to flowers names

```
    {
"1": "pink primrose",
"2": "hard-leaved pocket orchid",
"3": "canterbury bells",
"4": "sweet pea",
"5": "english marigold",
"6": "tiger lily",
"7": "moon orchid",
"8": "bird of paradise",
"9": "monkshood",
"10": "globe thistle",
"11": "snapdragon",
    }
```

My big problem is to get a class_to_idx mapping, how do I do this, my flower names do not match the images if I visualize them, I get totally different flower names for my flowers.

I first created a mapping by having a dict with key my original label before I subtracted 1, and value the one after. Example

```
    class_to_idx = {77:76, 73:72, 1:0, 65:64......102:101...65:54}
```

This is beyond doubt wrong as I was getting totally wrong label for my images.

The first label of my image in my data_dir_path = 'data/images' is 77, upon subtracting one I get 76. 
Would this mean the index for all labels 76 is 0, and if the next class is 72 , would that mean the index for all classes 72 is 1? So...

```
    class_to_idx = {76:0, 72:1, 0:2, 65:3....and so on}
```

The ImageFolder seems to have a class_to_idx attribute which if used on my Dataset throws an error,

```
    image_datasets['train'].class_to_idx

   AttributeError: 'MyDataset' object has no attribute 'class_to_idx'
```

This is obviously the case because my Dataset class does not contain any such attribute.

But seriously though, How do I map my classes to my index? This is super important as I need to checkpoint my model and load it back again to fire out predictions.It may sound really silly, but I really don't know what to do here, please help?

Comment: You can check `ImageFolder`'s [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/folder.html#ImageFolder) to get to know how `class_to_idx` is created. You can do something like this: `classes = os.listdir(/dir/)` then `class_to_idx = {classes[i]: i for i in range(len(classes))}` Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I was just checking it out but don't really understand what's happening, that gives me { 77: 250, 73: 444 and so on } but 250 is the index where the class changes, shoudlnt 77 be 0 since it is the first index?

Answer (score 0):

I finished this thing a long time back and for what it's worth I would like to give my two cents as to where I went wrong, super embarrassing though. I did not sort my image_path_list. The order they appeared in my data folder and the corresponding labels in the labels folder list did not match. This was because  Python was reading them in arbitrary order from the data folder into image_path_list. A simple sort sorted everything out.

```
    image_path_list = sort([os.path.join(self.root_dir, filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.root_dir)])
```

Comment: Its sorted, not sort. typo.